# Is the series of functions converges uniformly?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> is the following series of functions converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$?
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$$

What I've tried to do is finding a maximum point:

$$u'(x) = (-1)^{n-1} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n} = (-1)^{n-1} \frac{2x(1+x^2)^n - nx^2(1+x^2)^{n-1}2x}{(1+x^2)^{2n}} = (-1)^{n-1}\frac{2x(1+x^2)^{n-1}\cdot (1+x^2 -nx^2)}{(1+x^2)^{2n}}$$

$$u'(x) = 0 \iff 1+x^2 = nx^2 \iff x = \pm \sqrt \frac{1}{n-1}$$

Basically $x=0$ is a critical point too, but then we get a series of zeros.

Now, $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |S_N(x) - S(x)| \ge \left| \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n-1}}{(1+\frac{1}{n-1})^n}\right|$$

Is that what I am supposed to do here, or am I complicating things and missing a better solution?

Comment: Hint: Weierstrass M test.

Comment: Should I use those critical points I've found?